# Synology DS415+ setup USB Printer

Tags: macos, usb, nas, synology, laser-printer

I have a HP LaserJet P1102, I am trying to install it connected via USB cable to my NAS, I can not find my P1102 in my Mac, instead it was showing "usbprinter1@diskstation".
 If this printer is selected the printing window shows sending and printing but the printer does not print at all. 
 Any help is more than welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got HP LaserJet Pro P1102 connected to Synology DS110j to print from Mac through LPD.

Download and install driver pack from Apple (https://support.apple.com/kb/DL907).

System Preferences, Printers & Scanners, "+", Add Printer or Scanner..., IP tab.

Address - IP address or network name of DiskStation,
Protocol - Line Printer Daemon - LPD,
Queue - usbprinter1 (queue name can be found in DS's control panel, external devices, printers, name).

Name, Location - choose by yourself.

Use - Select software..., HP LaserJet Professional P1100, 6.9.

That's all, print test page and enjoy.

Comment: Hi Aleksey, thanks for the info, did you connect your HP printer direct to the USB port of your  NASs?

Comment: Yes, printer is connected directly to NAS via USB.

Comment: Dear Aleksey, you are great, works perfect in all Macs at home. Thanks a lot, I am sure many users will benefit from your help.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possible problems. The first one is that some NASs use the USB port only for thumb-drive support, not printers.

The second problem is that the P1102 is a "host-based" printer, which relies on the Mac's graphics engine to convert a page into dots on the page. Such printers are notoriously hard to network via a "printserver".

There are 2 ways to network them:

1. share the printer from a PC or Mac. This works reliably.
2. use a printserver that specifically supports your printer.

If you want to use method 2, look for a list of supported printers from the printserver manufacturer. If your printer model is not in the list, you must assume it will not work.

Synology have a printer support list [here](https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/Printer/What_USB_printers_does_Synology_Product_support), which includes the P1102w, up to OSX 10.6. More recent versions of OSX have not been tested, so they may not work. You could try and contact Synology to see if they have more up-to-date information. And, have a look at their [printer setup webpage](https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/Printer/How_to_set_up_network_printers_shared_from_Synology_NAS_on_Windows) - which only talks about Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply, I will contact synology their support is amazing